# WSS_Web Analytics Service Application database not found error

Tags: database, wss

I have received the following error for a while:

> A critical incident has occurred where a database was not found on server .
>   Event ID: 3760
>   Event Description: SQL Database 'WSS_Web Analytics Service Application' on SQL Server 
>   instance not found.

There is no such database on the SQL server, but it is listed in the Central Administration( Review database status). 
How can I fix this?

Can I remove a "WSS_Web Analytics Service Application" database from Central Administration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was able to fix the issue by recreating the service. It took about a week to see any data into the reports and I don't get the error any more.